# cant retrieve data from mysql db with php

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my bad English,
I cant retrieve record from mysql database, there's no error messages and nothing showing. The things is I want to retrieve data on a page with **session** using external php file. My table has data on it, I've inserted it with phpmyadmin. Here's the code :

**UPDATE**

I only work on php file now, and here the konek.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$konek=new mysqli('localhost','root','zxcvbnm','jumat') or die(mysqli_connect_error);

$selek=mysqli_query($konek,'select * from kategori');
    while($baris=mysqli_fetch_array($selek)){
        echo $baris['kodekat'].' '.$baris['namakat'];
        echo '<br>';
    }


if($konek){
    echo 'koneksi ok';
}


$konek->close();
?>
```

it only shows the *'koneksi ok'* word, is the while not processed?

thank you in advance

Comment: Try to print a string within `konek.php` and see if you've included the file ok.

Comment: What is your PHP version? mysql_* is depreceted as of PHP 5.5

Comment: Add this code at the start of your code so it will show you errors regarding your code. error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: i think `if($i<=mysql_fetch_array($selek))` is wrong statement. remove it and then check, hope it will work.

Comment: yes, its ok, I've add _if_ statement, then _echo_ something, it shows, after I mark my _php_ as comment,

Comment: @AdemÖztaş my php version is 5.5.15

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola is shows error, `syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE)`

Comment: @randuwe You should use PDO or mysqli, For the more information http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php , http://php.net/manual/tr/book.mysqli.php

Comment: there's no mysqli option, I'm using PHP from XAMPP linux,

Comment: Replace your require statement with require('php/konek.php'); and tell me what you get.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola require is not a function, refer to [http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php]

Comment: It says it's not necessary but why dont you try it and check what happen.

Comment: I've just try it, after read your comment, and it still no effect,

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do with this line:

```
if($i<=mysql_fetch_array($selek)){
```

If you are trying to compare with the no. of data use:

```
if($i<=mysql_num_rows($selek)){
```

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I had trouble with this traditional MySQL api.

I'll share this small PDO tutorial that got me over this mess, hope this helps you as much  as it helped me.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: how to install PDO or mysqli extension for PHP on XAMPP linux?

Comment: Hi mate, you don't need to install PDO extensions. I think PHP already supports this feature. The functions are already there 

sorry for late reply, i am working atm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$konek=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","zxcvbnm","jumat") or die(mysqli_error());
$selek=mysqli_query($konek,"select kodekat,namakat from kategori");
$i=0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($selek) > 0 ){
    while($baris = mysqli_fetch_array($selek)){
        $id = $baris["kodekat"];
        $nmk = $baris["namakat"];   

        echo"kode: ".$id."nama:".$nmk.'<br/>';
    }
}else{
    echo 'No items in database';    
}
mysqli_close($konek);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem.
Yhe problem is, my database is empty, I'm so forgetfull, :)
sorry for the inconvenience, I'm sorry I'm sorry,
the code is fine, all of them, :)
and all of answers above, I'm sure it works,
its my faults, that's my database was empty in the first place,